# Why do browsers render &nbsp; as a regular space character?

Tags: html, browser, whitespace

Consider the following HTML snippet:

```
<p>Space&nbsp;Test</p>
```

When this HTML is used in a web page and the page rendered by a browser, the character actually rendered by the browser between "Space" and "Test" is a regular space character (U+0020), not a non-breaking space character (U+00A0).

(This can be observed by, for example, using the Firefox extension [Character Identifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/character-identifier/).)

I tried this in Firefox 5, Internet Explorer 8, and Chrome 12; all had the same behavior of writing out U+0020 instead of U+00A0 on the rendered web page, even though though the source document contained `&nbsp;` rather than a regular space character.

Why do browsers render a regular space character instead of a non-breaking space character in this way?

Comment: U+00A0 has a decomposition link to U+0020. http://www.charbase.com/00a0-unicode-no-break-space  But that doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: Sounds like a browser bug. Has it been reported?

Comment: @ColonelPanic I didn't consider this to be a bug, since all major browsers seem to implement the behavior the same way.

Comment: See also “Non-breaking spaces (nbsp) not copied as such” (“https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359303”)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a relic of pre-Unicode times, when the NBSP character didn't exist in the standard character set.  HTML defined the `&nbsp;` escape sequence as simply a space that shouldn't cause word wrapping.

Comment: Interesting!  Do you have a link to where that is mentioned in the spec?

Comment: Yeah, this was actually defined in ISO8879, which was published in 1986 as part of the SGML spec, which HTML was based on.  You have to pay for a copy of the [actual standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=16388), but here is [a useful link](http://www.cs.vassar.edu/CES/sgml/ISOnum).  The [HTML 4 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) references it.

Comment: I found this from [the HTML 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/specialchars.html) digging through w3.org.

Comment: Ah, nice. That's an even more direct reference. :)